# Разбиение чисел на цифры

Tags: java

Сосчитать сумму цифр, при этом умножая каждую цифру на её порядковый номер (позицию) в числе, считая слева, начиная с единицы. Например 1567 - получается 1*1+5*2+6*3+7*4=57.

В этом коде вроде бы считает, но почему то выдает некорректный результат. Не пойму в чем проблема

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int a = 56;
    int sum = 0;        
       String s = a+"";
       for (int j=0;j<s.length(); j++){
           sum+=(j+1)*s.charAt(j);               
       }
       System.out.println(sum);    
}
```

Comment: У Вас, наверное, результат 161 получается. Цифры отображаются как цифры, но на самом деле это номер символа таблицы юникода. Получается вместо "5" там 53, а вместо "6" - 54.

Comment: Идея с использованием % и / была, но думал что можно как то иначе) Теперь все ясно, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Так у вас ничего работать не будет.
Если поставить цель сделать этот код рабочим, то пишите так:

```
int a = 56;
int sum = 0;
String s = String.valueOf(a);
for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
    sum +=(j+1)*Integer.valueOf(s.substring(j, j+1));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Главная причина нерабочего кода в том, что метод charAt возвращает вам char, который по сути является числовым представлением символа.
Поэтому расчет происходит именно исходя из этого числового представления, а не из фактического числа, которое вы видите в строке.

Но это плохой код. Преобразовывать инт в стринг и наоборот нецелесообразно. Вы тратите слишком много ресурсов: это медленные методы плюс нееоправданно большое количество объектов , разумеется , занимают память.

Для таких подсчетов просто делите число на 10, каждый раз получая цифру. Узнав все цифры, выполняйте с ними необходимые вычисления.

Answer (score 2):

Метод  `String.charAt()` возвращает `char`.

В `java`, `char` это числовое представление символа. Поэтому следующий код вполне себе работоспособный.

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
int i = a + b;
System.out.println(i);
```

Ошибок компиляции он не выдаст.

В данном случае:

```
a = 97
b = 98
```

В вашем случае:

```
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
```

---

Поскольку задачка учебная, дам только подсказку. Используйте оператор деления (/) и оператор получения остатка (%).

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано в других ответах - метода `charAt` возвращает тип `char`, в котором хранится код символа. В случае, если вы хотите использовать свою реализацию, но при этом, чтобы она работала правильно, то можно из каждого кода символа-цифры вычесть код символа `0` - получится правильное значение цифры. Код тогда будет следующим:

```
int a = 56;
int sum = 0;
String s = a + "";
for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
    sum += (j + 1) * (s.charAt(j) - '0');
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Но всё же, лучше решать такие задачи арифметически, а не через строки.

Answer (score -1):

```
        int num = 1567;
        int len = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (num > 0) {
            digits.add(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
            len++;
        }

        int sum = 0;

        for (Integer digit : digits) {
            sum += digit * len;
            len--;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
```